# Trying to deploy an ML model through Tkinter. the code runs and the GUI shows but the results are not shown despite the system running with no error

Tags: python, tkinter, catboostregressor

Trying to create a GUI that takes attributes of a building a returns a value from a trained ML model using Tkinter. the application runs without error but returns no results. having hard time finding the problem. here is the whole code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time; 
import datetime
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor 
import numpy as np 
import joblib
import json

#load model and scaler
from_file = CatBoostRegressor()
house_model=from_file.load_model("final_housing_model",format="coreml")
house_scaler=joblib.load("housing_scaler.pkl")

#create the very thing(GUI)

house =Tk()
house.title('Veracity')
house.geometry("1600x800+0+0")

#declare stuff
text_Input=IntVar()
#creating the frames for Top, Bottom and Side parts of the GUI

Bottom=Frame(house,width=900,height=700,bg="powder blue",relief=SUNKEN )
Bottom.pack(side=LEFT)


#time tuu nta kindi (the fromat is not good for the moment)
localtime=time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time( )))

#Put Text Content in the thing(as in just the title)
Topinfo=Label(Tops,font=("Helvetica",50,"bold"),text="VeracityReference",fg="black",bd=10,anchor='w')
Topinfo.grid(row=0,column=0)
#time as well from above
time=Label(Tops,font=("Helvetica",20,"bold"),text=localtime,fg="black",bd=10,anchor='w')
time.grid(row=1,column=0)
# the inputs of the value determinants for now

bedroomsinput=IntVar()
bathroomsinput=IntVar()

#Bedrooms
bedrooms_ref=Label(Bottom,font=('Times New Roman',16,'bold'),text="Number of 
 Bedrooms",bd=10,anchor='w')
bedrooms_ref.grid(row=0,column=0)
bedrooms=Entry(Bottom,font 
("arial",16,"bold"),textvariable=bedroomsinput,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg='white',justify='right')
bedrooms.grid(row=0,column=1)
#Bathrooms
bathrooms_ref=Label(Bottom,font=('Times New Roman',16,'bold'),text='Number of 
bathrooms',bd=10,anchor='w')
bathrooms_ref.grid(row=1,column=0)
bathrooms=Entry(Bottom,font= 
("arial",16,"bold"),textvariable=bathroomsinput,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg='white',justify='right')
bathrooms.grid(row=1,column=1)


#put them together 
S_bedrooms=float(bedrooms.get())
S_bathrooms=float(bathrooms.get())
S_sqft_living=float(sqft_living.get())
S_sqft_lot=float(Sqft_lot.get())
S_floors=float(Number_of_floors.get())

inputh=
```

[[S_bedrooms,S_bathrooms]]

```
#function to do stuff
def return_predictions(model=house_model,scaler=house_scaler,House=inputh):
    S_bedrooms=float(bedrooms.get())
    S_bathrooms=float(bathrooms.get())
    House=
```

[[S_bedrooms,S_bathrooms]]
        House=scaler.transform(House)

```
    Market_value=model.predict(House)

    return  Market_value

results=return_predictions(house_model,house_scaler,inputh)

submit=Button(Bottom,padx=16,pady=8,bd=16,fg='black',font= 
('Arial',16,'bold'),width=10,text="submit",bg="powder 
blue",command=return_predictions).grid(row=9,column=6)

Market_value_ref=Label(Bottom,font=('Times New Roman',16,'bold'),text="Estimated Market 
Value",bd=10,anchor='w')
Market_value_ref.grid(row=7,column=6)
Market_value=Entry(Bottom,font= 
("arial",16,"bold"),textvariable=results,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg='white',justify='right')
Market_value.grid(row=8,column=6)


house.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Please try to condense it down to a [mcve]. We don't need dozens of labels if the problem is that no labels at all are showing - one or two will do. Also, I don't see anywhere where you take the data out of `house_model` and put it into widgets, so I'm not sure why you think the data should be visible.

Comment: Thanks@BryanOakley, I have reduced the code as advised. I was thinking that the return_predictions function is doing that, that it takes the widgets input using the .get() method. transforms them into the array an inputs them in the model(house_Model after scaling them) and the outputs them in the Market_Value as results. the issue is that no error is shown yet no results is displayed either. #tkinter #python #catboostregressor

Comment: "no results displayed" is just too vague. You need to explain what results you're expecting. Also, there appears to be problems with your formatting.